# "lrange()" function isn't working on redis-py

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I have a Redis db locally on my machine, and I store lists in it.
The storing process works fine, but I can't access the lists via pytho code.

I tried doing:

```
redis_data = redis_client.lrange('TLV-NYC', 0, -1)
# or
redis_data = redis_client.lrange('TLV-NYC', int(0), int(-1))
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError("int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'")
```

I tried accessing the lists with redis-cli and it worked,
my redis version is 4.5.1.

Hope someone could help.

Comment: Hi, I get the exact same error from the first one: TypeError("int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'")

Comment: Post [mre], incl. Full traceback

Comment: For some reason it's working now, don't know what changed...